# ora-01841 full year must be between 4713 and 9999 and not be 0

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have been working on a query that is making me go crazy because I couldn't seem to understand the error message: my query is:

```
SELECT  MYTABLE." ID ", 


  NVL(max(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(MYTABLE." XISSU_DT " ,MYTABLE." XTNR "), 'DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD/MM/YYYY')),  TO_DATE(SYSDATE , 'DD/MM/YYYY') )  MAXLASTINSDATE,

   TO_DATE(SYSDATE , 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 


      (TO_CHAR (TO_DATE(SYSDATE , 'DD/MM/YYYY')
           - TO_DATE(NVL(max(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(MYTABLE." XISSU_DT " ,MYTABLE." XTNR "), 'DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD/MM/YYYY')),  TO_DATE(SYSDATE , 'DD/MM/YYYY') ) , 'DD/MM/YYYY')) * -1) MaturityPeriod


     FROM MYTABLE
where  
MYTABLE." STATUS " = 'A'
group by MYTABLE." ID "
```

the Error I have been getting is:

```
ora-01841 full year must be between 4713 and 9999 and not be 0
```

Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: `sysdate` is already a date! Don't do `TO_DATE(SYSDATE , 'DD/MM/YYYY')`, just refer to it directly. (I won't even ask why you have column names with spaces like that....) What is you current NLS_DATE_FOIRMAT setting?

Comment: Perhaps more pertinently, what is the largest value you have for `" XTNR "`. If that''s  quite large (maybe only tens of thousands) then you could well be just adjusting `" XISSU_DT "` to an invalid date.

Comment: Do you really have identifiers with leading and trailing spaces? Calling columns things like `" ID "` is insane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(datevalue, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD/MM/YYYY')` is removing any time component which is effectively the same as: `TRUNC( datevalue )`.

Then `TO_DATE(SYSDATE , 'DD/MM/YYYY')` is probably where your error lies as `TO_DATE( stringvalue, format_model )` takes a string as the first argument so you are effectively doing:

```
TO_DATE(
  TO_CHAR(
    SYSDATE,
    ( SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT' )
  ),
  'DD/MM/YYYY'
)
```

It doesn't make sense as `SYSDATE` is already of the `DATE` data type so you don't need to use `TO_DATE` with it.

Finally, `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - datevalue)*-1` Why are you converting it to a string then multiplying it by a number when you can just do:

```
(SYSDATE - datevalue)*-1
```

But you don't even need the `*-1` as you can just swap the terms around:

```
(datevalue - SYSDATE)
```

Tidying it all up you want something like:

```
SELECT  MYTABLE." ID ", 
        NVL(
          MAX( TRUNC( ADD_MONTHS(MYTABLE." XISSU_DT " ,MYTABLE." XTNR ") ) ),
          SYSDATE
        ) MAXLASTINSDATE,
        SYSDATE, 
        ( NVL(
            MAX( TRUNC( ADD_MONTHS(MYTABLE." XISSU_DT " ,MYTABLE." XTNR ") ) ),
            SYSDATE
          )
          - SYSDATE
        ) AS MaturityPeriod
FROM   MYTABLE
where  MYTABLE." STATUS " = 'A'
group by MYTABLE." ID "
```